# Is a Guid a primitive type or a complex type?

Tags: c#, .net, object, types, casting

We separate out extension method classes by primitive types and complex types that we are extending. My question is simple. Would a Guid be considered a primitive type along with string, int, DateTime, etc? Or would it be considered a complex type when describing it?

### Update

After reviewing the answers I much appreciate the clarification that I was able to glean from some answers. However, I am getting the impression that curiosity <strike>killed the cat</strike> got the cat murdered, so I am voting to close my own question.

Comment: Define "primitive type" first :)

Comment: Define primitive and complex types.

Comment: Well I guess that is the real question. How would you folks define it?

Comment: The primitive types are typically those listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360%28v=vs.80%29.aspx  ...correct? MSDN is calling them 'Built-In Data Types".

Comment: @IAbastract - As far as .NET is concerned, yes.

Comment: I would go to the person who made this policy and say 1) "Why?" 2) "Which is `Guid`" ? 3) "What's the decision procedure so I don't have to bother you next time this comes up?" Hopefully somewhere along the way enlightenment will dawn in you and/or them.

Comment: @Alex Oh come on. You question is "Is GUID a primitive type or a complex type" where primitive and complex are terms that you also have to specify. That's silly. This is not a real question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Calm yourself. I was simply curious how you guys would classify the Guid type. I did some googling and found conflicting results and conflicting definitions.

Comment: @AakashM It's not really a big deal for the project. I was just curious what --you folks-- the rabid pack of dogs thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you call a "primitive data type".

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) lists these two definitions:

- a basic type is a data type provided by a programming language as a basic building block. Most languages allow more complicated composite types to be recursively constructed starting from basic types.
- a built-in type is a data type for which the programming language provides built-in support.

According to the first one, `Guid` is a constructed type, **not** a primitive.

According to the second, it is also **not** a primitive type (as it is provided in the BCL, in the `System` namespace, and is not defined by any of the .NET languages).

---

Update:

This is what the [`IsPrimitive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx) method of the `Type` class says:

> The primitive types are Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single.

So, as far as .NET is concerned, it is **not** a primitive type.

---

In conclusion: According to the three separate criteria above, `Guid` is **definitely not** a primitive type.

Comment: Interesting. So really @Jason is right when he says the answer to this is murky.

Comment: @Alex - Yes. The answer is context dependent.

Comment: @Downvoter - care to comment?

Comment: The programming language C# does NOT provide built-in support for `Guid` (it's defined in the .NET Framework, not the language). Thus, your conclusion that per the second definition it is a primitive type is not correct.

Comment: @Jason - Thanks for the correction. I read built-in incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Guid would be a primitive by your definition. It's a struct like `int`, `DateTime`. It's also provided by the .NET Framework in the `System` namespace. Plus, it's immutable, like `string` and `DateTime`.

By .NET's definion it isn't.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx

*I would lump it in the same category as `int`, `DateTime` and `string`.*

Comment: I would call it a value type rather than a primitive type.

Comment: True, all structs in C# are value types.

Comment: Would DateTime be a value type?

Comment: Yes because it is a `struct`.

Comment: @Alex You can look this up trivially.

Comment: @Alex: Yes. Though, `string` (from your list) is not technically a value type, but an immutable reference type...

Comment: @DanielA.White http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx shows that Guid is also a `struct`. So I guess they are both value types. Thank you :)

Comment: Correct. `struct` == value type.

Comment: I would not lump the three together. One is a value type defined by the language, another is a value type defined by the .NET Framework, and the latter is an immutable reference type defined by the language.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is somewhat murky.

The language specification states:

> it is also possible to use structs and operator overloading to implement new “primitive” types in the C# language

which would seemingly imply that `Guid` is a "primitive" type. However `Type` provides a `IsPrimitive` property and `typeof(Guid).IsPrimitive` will return `false`.

Note, though, that `Guid` is not provided by the language but rather by the .NET Framework.

The language specification also states that the primitive types in C# are `Boolean` (`bool`), `Byte` (`byte`), `SByte` (`sbyte`), `Int16` (`short`), `UInt16`, `Int32` (`int`), UInt32 (`uint`), `Int64` (`long`), UInt64 (`ulong`), `IntPtr`, `UIntPtr`, `Char` (`char`), `Double` (`double`), and `Single` (`single`) notably leaving out both `DateTime` and `Guid`.

I would lose the descriptor "primitive" altogether and just refer to `Guid` as a value type.

Comment: Okay, I agree that it is not primitive. So if you had to describe a Guid, how would you categorize its type?

Comment: I agree. C# specification clearly define term "primitive" and it would be messy if everyone would reinvent his own terminology and call string as value type because it has value sematics.

Comment: @Alex Ford: and why you need this distinction between primitive and non-primitive types at all?

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov I don't. I was simply curious. I'm getting the impression that being curious is a fault.

Comment: @Alex: absolutely not. But it seems from your question that you're trying inveting the wheel:) BTW, DateTime is not primitive type;) P.S. there is a very simple way to check whether particular type primitive or not: Guid.NewGuid().GetType().IsPrimitive.Dump();

Comment: That first bit of the spec you quoted is confusing and I've asked Mads to remove it in a future edition. There's no need for the C# language spec to ever define "primitive type" and it is unfortunate that this language ended up in there.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you call a "primitive type." The [Type Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301569.aspx) article says, "Any data types directly supported by the compiler are called primitive types.". I don't expect that the compiler "knows" about `System.Guid`.

The article [Primitive data types in C#](http://www.csharpcourses.com/2008/06/primitive-data-types-in-c.html) doesn't list `System.Guid` among the primitive types.

One could argue that it has to be a composite type, since it's a 128-bit entity that consists of multiple other primitives.

I'd say that GUID is NOT a primitive type, but you'll probably get others who disagree with me.