# Service reference generated from .Net tool replaces GUID with string

Tags: c#, wsdl, guid, generated-code

I am using the .Net tool wsdl.exe to generate a service reference for a webservice from the WSDL. One of the methods on the service takes in a `Guid` as a parameter. When I look at the code that is generated, the parameter is now a `string`.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

All values to and from a web service must be primitive types, and are serialised to be such - the consumers may very well be using a variety of platforms, the specific `Guid` type would mean nothing to anyone not on a .NET platform.

As to whether `Guid` is a primitive type, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475884/is-a-guid-a-primitive-type-or-a-complex-type).